# Why the addtion of ++overloaded operation results into unexpted values?

Tags: c++

See the code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class A{
   private:
      int i;
   public:
      A()
      {
         i=10;
      }
      A operator++(int)
      {
         A tmp=*this;
         i +=1;
         return tmp;  
      }
      display()
      {
         cout<<i;
      }
};
int main()
{
   A a,b;
   b=a++ + a++;
   cout<<endl<<b<<"\t"<<a;
   return 0;
}
```

For the statement `b = a++ + a++`, the expected value we think will be 20,
But the above statement resulted into 21.

How?

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please provide a short complete example. What you have there will not compile.

Comment: Are you just trying something out or is it meant in actual productcode? If for productcode I really hope you _don't_ use this. Meanly because of readability.

Comment: Why do people still try to understand such nonsense statements? Some of them aren't undefined behaviour, but still: they are hardly readable and - as it is in this case - intuition is mostly wrong. Stop it!

Comment: `<iostream.h>` is not a standard header. Use `<iostream>`. This sample doesn't use anything from `<conio.h>`, either.

Comment: "the expected value we think will be 20", why?

Comment: In the operator overload, why not just say `return *this;`?

Comment: @Panzercrisis: If you do that, `tmp` becomes usesless, and once you remove its declaration, you end up with a pre increment operator instead of a post increment operator.

Comment: @Panzercrisis, because in post increment operator we want to return value that object had before incrementing

Answer (score 3):

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), your code is equals to `b = (a++) + (a++)`
So, computing it, we have:

```
a = 10;
tmp1 = a++;//tmp1 = 10, a = 11
tmp2 = a++;//tmp2 = 11, a = 12
b = tmp1 + tmp2 // 10 + 11 = 21
```

Also remember that constructions like `b = a++ + a++;` are very poor readable, so you should always use brackets, also it's always a good idea to avoid using increments and decrements like `a++` in complex expressions. Readability is much better than showing that you know operator priorities.

Answer (score 2):

As Charles pointed out `++` called on A object are function calls. Thus you first increment i from 10 to 11 and return 10, then in the second call you increment i from 11 to 12 and return 11. The you add 10 and 11 ending up with 21.

Comment: I was under the impression this is defined because both operators are the same (`++`).

Comment: But both `++` are function calls. The writes happen in separate statements in separate function calls so there are intervening "sequence points", to use the old terminology. This isn't the reason that the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The first call increments `a` to 11 and returns 10. The second call increments `a` to 12 and returns 11. Sounds like 21 is correct.

That said, the order of evaluation (which `++` is "the first call") is *unspecified* (thanks JD), so using it twice in the same expression is generally not a good idea.

Comment: Note that which call it the first is undefined. Can be any of the two. Not that this will change the result anyway.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal:  Pedantry -- not *undefined*, but *unspecified*.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, what's the difference, if both calls are the same?

Comment: @cpp: You can take an Audi to the shops, or a bike to the shops. The outcome is the same: you're at the shops... but that doesn't change the fact that the two vehicles are not very much alike.

Comment: Right. You can't say whether this is evaluated as 11 + 10 or 10 + 11. So you wouldn't want to do this in `a++ * f(a++)` for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I shall render my answer in the form of a simple comparison.

Your code is:

```
b = a++ + a++;
```

I think you rather confused it with:

```
b = a + (a++)++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Overloaded operators are just functions with funny names. They don't neccesarily behave the same as built-in ones. If you're tempted to do the same expression with an object of built-in type - don't, the behaviour would be undefined.

You haven't shown the definition of `operator+` for `A` - I'll asume it's a free function. The expression `b = a++ + a++;` can then be rewritten as

```
b = operator+( a.operator++(0), a.operator++(0) );
```

Hope that helps make things clearer.

The two calls to postfix increment are indeterminately sequenced - that means we can't know which one will be called first. It doesn't matter in your case, since they're both called on the same object, but don't rely on any particular order - it need not be consistent, even during the same execution of the program.